# How to add facebook application to page as tab

Tags: php, facebook

How can i add a Facebook application to my page?Now there is no option to view application profile page.Can you please hep me how i can add this to my page?

Thanks,

Comment: See FB Dev FAQ link. https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=172925542764476#How-can-I-add-more-apps-to-my-Facebook-Page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They removed application profile page for some reasons. You can find a document about 'Add Page Tab Dialog' here. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this site:
http://www.addtab.info/

Comment: I think that the fact we need to use external tools to get things done, and very basic things in fact is **rediculus**! Facebook really needs to get his shit together...

/nagging

Comment: This is a very bad comment.  As serious developers for a 3rd party API, It is solely **OUR** responsibility to keep updated with the changes that facebook makes to their platform.  Any change made is first placed in their [developers roadmap](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/) and talked about in their [developers blog](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/) **well** before the change is implemented.  It is a fast paced, ever-changing world of social interaction.  And we have to behave accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

for Tabs you just can use this link:

`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR APP ID&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com`

for Apps you have to change the redirect_url to an url owned by the app.

Answer (score 1):

I've put together a javascript snippet that is intended to be used as a bookmarklet. If you use the bookmarklet while on an application's page in the developers section, a new window will automatically open with the add to page-dialog. To use it, just copy the minified code from the repository below and create a new bookmark for "javascript:[the code]" (without the quotation marks).

https://github.com/Wehrzie/Add-Facebook-Application-to-Page-Bookmarklet

Hopefully this will help some until Facebook cleans up their current, quite messy, solution.